# How to combine 2 variables in bar chart by using ggplot in R studio?

Tags: r, variables, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm trying to plot a multivariate bar chart by using ggplot such that one bar consist of two different colour which represent two variables instead of comparing the 2 variables side by side. The 2 variables will be positive probability (`P.Probability`) and negative probability (`N.Probability`).

The code below is my data. I'm only able to include `P.Probability` in the code but I want both `P.Probability` and `N.Probability` to be included in the graph as I mentioned above.

```
Month <- c("Aug", "Sep", "Oct")
P.Probability <- c(0.5, 0.6, 0.6)
N.Probability <- 1-P.Probability

dtf2 <- data.frame(Month, P.Probability, N.Probability)

ggplot(dtf2, aes(x = Month, y = P.Probability)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=0)+
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.line.y = element_line(color="black", size = 0.5))+
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(P.Probability*100, "%"), vjust = ifelse(P.Probability >= 0, -0.5, 1.2)))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent)
```

The diagram attached below is the graph that I want. I hope the `N.Probability` will be the blue colour as the bottom and the `P.Probability` will be the red colour on top.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest gathering into long format so you can map the type of probability to fill color.

```
dtf2_long <- tidyr::gather(dtf2, type, Probability, -Month)

ggplot(dtf2_long, aes(x = Month, y = Probability, fill = type)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=0)+
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.line.y = element_line(color="black", size = 0.5))+
  geom_text(data = dtf2_long %>% filter(type == "P.Probability"),
            aes(label = paste(Probability*100, "%"), vjust = ifelse(Probability >= 0, -0.5, 1.2)))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It works for me:) However, how should I do to make the N.Probability at the bottom and P.Probability at the top, the graph you shown seems like inverted as what I want. Further, is it possible to change the colour such that N.Probability is black and P.Probbility is red? Thanks!